# Issue in implementing a datatable button (HTML5 export)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Iam new in codeigniter. And this is first time iam using a datatable. The datatable works fine with features such as sorting,searching etc. but i need to implement an export button. I have loaded the javascript files and css files required for datatble button yet no favourable output.Can this problem be solved

this is the javascript code iam using

```
  table = $('#user_data').DataTable({ 

       "dom": '<"top"iB>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
       "buttons": [
                    {extend:'pdfHtml5',text:'Save as Pdf',key:'p'}
                    ],
    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.
     "bFilter":false,
     "ordering":false,
     'bLengthChange': false,
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "fetch_print_list",
        "type": "POST",
        //"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "data": function ( data ) {
            data.branch = $('#branch').val();
            data.fromdate = $('#fromdate').val();
            data.view_by = $('#view_by').val();
        },
    },
    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],

});
```

this are the files i have loaded

```
 <script src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.css');?>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js');?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/Buttons-1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css');?>"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/Buttons-1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js');?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resource/DataTables/Buttons-1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js');?>"></script>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: iam sorry iam not familiar with fiddle.....

Comment: https://codepen.io/ on this url, you just need to paste your code to replicate issue

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. I applied the code at the mentione dsite and it works properly but iam stilll having issue in my real work. When i run the code in https://codepen.io/ iam getting a warning message     "DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"   . I guess the issue is because of the url i have called in ajax. The url in ajax function points to a function in controller page.

Comment: Share codepen link!!! it's unique link!!

Comment: https://codepen.io/sruthirbabu/pen/OEGagZ